# sql CE, table description and others informations

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

so,
i created a table in Sql CE.
if a run

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t1
```

i don't have any informations about it

```
TABLE__CATALOG  TABLE__SCHEMA   TABLE__NAME TABLE__TYPE TABLE__GUID DESCRIPTION TABLE__PROPID   DATE__CREATED   DATE__MODIFIED
NULL    NULL    cxvpeqja4a00l3fb2n0fqp0r    TABLE   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

why?
could be possible to add description, creation date, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

My free Visual Studio extension "SQL Server Compact Toolbox" allows you you to add table and column descriptions.

Comment: yes, i know, but i would add in the db...could be possible? why view gives that informations if are not editable?

Comment: To be compatible with the information_schema standard!